# kendo ui on-demand RTL support with script

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I created an Autocomplete form. I followed [this simple documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/accessibility/supporting-rtl-languages) to create a button together with its click handler script. Clicking this button shall toggle RTL support for the form.

I have a problem. When I click the button, it does not toggle RTL support for the form.

[demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AfeNi)

```
<body>

<input type="button" id="toggleRTL" value="Activate RTL Support" class="k-button" />
<script>
$('#toggleRTL').on('click', function(event) {
    var form = $('#speakerForm');
    if (form.hasClass('k-rtl')) {
        form.removeClass('k-rtl')
    } else {
        form.addClass('k-rtl');
    }
})
</script>

<input id="autocomplete" type="text" />
<script>
    $("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: {
            data: [
            {name: "Google"}, 
            {name: "Bing"}
            ]
                     },
        dataTextField: "name",
     })
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: if you landed here looking for RTL support for kenod Angular inputs, then sadly this isnt supported. but you vote for it to be [here](https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/1417261-rtl-support-for-kendo-kendodateinputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missing some point from the tutorial :

1. you need to put all of your component to a **container** **element** and apply the **k-rtl class** to the container
2. you have a problem on your js where you dont have element with id **speakerForm**

UPDATE
3. as your comment i, i observe the behavior of the k-rtl and kendo autocomplete widget and the result is the suggestion will be still on the left side if we create the widget first then adding the k-rtl clas. So what do we need is the container having the k-rtl class first then initializing the widget. 
4. i updated my code so that every time you click the button the #autocomplete div will be removed with its parent( result from kendo autocomplete which is a span) then append new element and re-initializing the kendo autocompelete widget

I think it's working if you follow it like this

```js
 function createAutoComplete(){
     if($("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete") != null){
       $("#autocomplete").parent().remove();
        $("#container").append("<input id='autocomplete' type='text' />")
     }
   
     $("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
      dataSource: {
        data: [{
          name: "Google"
         }, {
          name: "Bing"
        }]
      },
      dataTextField: "name",
    });
 }
 createAutoComplete();
 $('#toggleRTL').on('click', function(event) {
   var form = $('#container');
   console.log(form);
   if (form.hasClass('k-rtl')) {
     console.log("test1");
     form.removeClass('k-rtl')
   } else {
     console.log("test2");
     form.addClass('k-rtl');
   }
   createAutoComplete();
   
 })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <input type="button" id="toggleRTL" value="Activate RTL Support" class="k-button" />
    <input id="autocomplete" type="text" />
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and your correction. After applying your code, clicking the button changes the form direction to right. Text inside the form -google and bing- is still LTR directed. It will be really appreciated if you can further assist in this point. Here is a very simple example demo: (http://dojo.telerik.com/UhuNu)

Comment: Thank you very much for your Update 3. It works perfectly without any side effect.
Based on your code, I have created a very simple demo (http://dojo.telerik.com/AwomI) by adding only a data-href template to open links in the same tab. When I moved the data to a separate json file, links did not worked? May you please assist in [this](http://fastrezult.com/kendo-autocomplete-test)? Shall I start this as a new "Ask Question"? Thanks again for your solution.

Comment: @Basem yes please, you need to explain more about the problem itself, so if i'm unable to answer it someone else may be able to solve it

Comment: OK. Thanks very much for your clarification

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your dojo.

http://dojo.telerik.com/AfeNi/4

But as @machun has stated you are missing some elements of the mechanics of this process.

I have added the missing form element speakerForm and then added some additional console.log() statements showing the actions being performed.

if you need any more info let me know.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and your correction. Thanks also for the updated dojo. Clicking the button changes the form direction to right. Text inside the form -google and bing- is still LTR directed. It will be really appreciated if you can further assist in this point. Here is a very simple example demo: (http://dojo.telerik.com/UhuNu)

Comment: so do you also need google and bing to be r-tl e.g. elgoog and gnib?

Comment: Thanks again for your care. I don't want reversed characters like elgoog and gnib. I want the whole word -google and bing- to be in the right side of the form box like this example: (http://dojo.telerik.com/UhuNu)

Comment: if you change it to the body rather then the form tag as per dojo it works fine http://dojo.telerik.com/AfeNi/8

Comment: Thank you very much. But still a very little step as I think. Clicking the button again does not change the direction. The target is to change between RTL and LTR. I will be thankful if you please further help regarding this step.

Comment: **Update to my previous comment** Your code here (http://dojo.telerik.com/AfeNi/8 ) is really very simple, clear, and straightforward. So I tried it many times on different browsers. I found that it works without problems on Firefox. On Chrome and Safari, after the first button click, the form and the text inside it does not change the direction. Although this, browser's console does not show any errors. May you please check it? Thankfully, I think that you can discover where the the issue is.

Comment: I have updated the dojo again. this should now work in chrome http://dojo.telerik.com/AfeNi/15 I have added the attribute `dir` to the body tag and swapping this from ltr/rtl support.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. It works perfectly. May you please post your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435532/kendo-ui-rtl-and-ltr-issue-in-chrome-and-safari-browsers) to check mark it as a solution for the problem