# kendo ui autocomplete - json file datasource - template - 404 Not Found error - /undefined URL

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-template, kendo-autocomplete

Below code has been thankfully provided by [machun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33358876/781159) for toggling between RTL and LTR directions in Kendo UI widgets.

The code consists of:

**HTML:**
kendo autocomplete form plus a button to activate support for RTL and LTR language.

**Script:**

- k-rtl class container
- datasource (json file)
- kendo autocomplete widget initializing + template to show image beside data and to open data links in the same tab
- k-rtl class

The problem is that links don't open correctly. It shows a 404 Not Found error plus a /undefined at the end of the URL.

[Live demo](http://fastrezult.com/kendo-autocomplete-test)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Untitled</title>

          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
          <div id="container">
            <input type="button" id="toggleRTL" value="Activate RTL Support" class="k-button" />
            <input id="autocomplete" type="text" />
          </div>

        </body>

        </html>
```

```js
<script>
    /*------k-rtl class container----------*/
    function createAutoComplete(){
          if($("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete") != null){
            $("#autocomplete").parent().remove();
            $("#container").append("<input id='autocomplete' type='text' />")
          }
    /*------datasource (json file)---------*/
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
    read: {
    url: "json.txt",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
    q: "javascript"
    }
    }
    },
    schema: {
    data: "results"
    }
    });
    /*------kendo autocomplete widget initializing + template to show image beside data and to open data links in the same tab----------*/
          $("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                dataTextField: "name",
                template: '<span><img src="/kendo-autocomplete-test/img/#: id #.jpg"  /></span>' + '<span data-href="#:link#">#:name#</span>',
                select: function(e) {
                    var href = e.item.find("span").data("href");
                    location.assign(href);
                }
            });
     }
    /*------k-rtl class----------*/
     createAutoComplete();
     $('#toggleRTL').on('click', function(event) {
       var form = $('#container');
       console.log(form);
       if (form.hasClass('k-rtl')) {
         console.log("test1");
         form.removeClass('k-rtl')
       } else {
         console.log("test2");
         form.addClass('k-rtl');
       }
       createAutoComplete();
     })
    </script>
```

Comment: @machun may you please have a look at this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice to debug your function first then simply check the variable and make sure it contain the right thing. You overlooked a simple thing that your **jquery dom selector** isn't quite right resulting **var href** contain "**undefined**".

Change

```
 var href = e.item.find("span").data("href");
```

To

```
var href = e.item.find("span[data-href]").attr("data-href");
```

Take a look [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/UPugI/2)

Comment: Thanks machun. Thanks very much. And sorry for overlooking things